# SSH User CA: Sign a user certificate with selected hosts instead of all hosts?

Tags: ssh, openssh, certificates

I have many servers that shares a common `TrustedUserCAKeys`. I want to sign a user certificate so it grants some access on specific servers instead of all of them.

For example, the following command generates a certificate that can be used to log in as root on all servers:

```
ssh-keygen -s ca -I example -n root id_rsa.pub
```

I tried the following command, but it generates a certificate that's ... useless.

```
ssh-keygen -s ca -I example -n root@server1 id_rsa.pub
```

I intended to generate a certificate that can only sign in as root on server1, but not root on any other server. I've made sure that `server1` is the FQDN on that server (or the complete content of `/etc/hostname`). Is there a way to achieve this without touching `sshd_config` on any host?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without changing the `sshd_config` file, the answer is generally no. The mechanism to pull this off is to setup an `AuthorizedPrincipalsFile` (or `AuthorizedPrincipalsCommand`). Without this directive in `sshd_config`, the default behavior is that the username for the authentication attempt must be listed literally as one of the principals embedded in the certificate. This is why 'root' works, but 'root@server1' does not.

In order to make a certificate using 'root@server1' work (without adding entries into `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys`), you would need to configure an `AuthorizedPrincipalsFile` for the root user (later OpenSSH versions permit this directive inside a `Match` block), and list 'root@server1', and do something similar on other servers. You can also extend this to permit certificates applicable to groups of servers, like 'root@dev' or even 'root@*', as long as each appropriate flavor is listed as a principal in the `AuthorizedPrincipalsFile`.

Another way of implementing this, is to explicitly list the CA key and allowed principals in the `.ssh/authorized_keys` file, using both the `cert-authority` and `principals=`  options. These are covered in the `sshd` man page description of the Authorized_Keys File Format.

Comment: Can you give an example of the file specified in `AuthorizedPrincipalsFile`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is when you issue ssh certificate if you directly put `root` 
 in `Principals` you will be giving access to all the servers which trust your CA.

To avoid this never issue a certificate with `username`. Instead create a strategy for access. A typical scenario is some people need access to testing servers, some need access to database servers and some need access to all the servers.
So I create multiple principles

- `project-dev`  - Access to Development/Testing Servers
- `project-databases` - Access to database servers
- `project-super` - Access to all the servers

To achieve this add `AuthorizedPrincipalsFile /etc/ssh/auth_principals/%u` in `sshd_config` file.

So when someone tries to log in to a server with `root` username, it will check file `/etc/ssh/auth_principals/root` (notice `%u` stands for user).

So if user certificate has a principle listed in this file user will be given access.

Authorised principles file for this scenario will be

- Dev Servers - `project-dev\nproject-super`
- Database Servers - `project-dev\nproject-super`
- Production Servers - `project-super`

So create a strategy as per your needs.

Note : If you still issue certificate with `root` in `Principles` It would still work. So avoid that.

I wrote a blog to setup complete ssh certificate infrastructure :

https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-use-ssh-certificates-for-scalable-secure-and-more-transparent-server-access-720a87af6617